# I want to do an animation when to change the image view of the service

Tags: android, animation, service, imageview, tween

There is `setimage ()` and `setWeather ()` method to change the image.
I want to be a tween animation , when `setweather` and `setimage` is called on the service.
I need your help.

```
  @Override
        public void onCreate() {
            super.onCreate();
            mIv = new ImageView(this);
            mIv.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
            mContentResolver = getContentResolver();
            mProviderObserver = new ContentObserver(new Handler()){
        @Override
        public void onChange(boolean selfChange, Uri uri) {
            super.onChange(selfChange, uri);
            if(uri.compareTo(mUri) == 0 ){
                String weather =mContentResolver.getType(uri);
                setWeather( weather);
            }
        }
        };
        mContentResolver.registerContentObserver(mUri, true, mProviderObserver);
        rnsmc= new ReadNewSmsMissedCall(mContentResolver);
        rnsmc.setChangeTelephonyListener(new ChangeTelephonyListener() {
            public void onChange() {
                setImage();
            }
        });
        rnsmc.registerObserver();
            setImage();
            mHandler = new Handler();
            mRunnable = new Runnable(){
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if(count == 1){
                        setImage();
                        count = 2;
                    }
                    else if(count == 2){
                        weather = mContentResolver.getType(mUri);
                        setWeather(weather);
                        ount = 1;
                    }
                mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable, 1000);
                } 
            };
            mRunnable.run();
            mTask = new TimerTask(){
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    new DoTask().execute(url);
                    setWeather(weather);
                }
            };
                mTimer = new Timer();
                mTimer.schedule(mTask, 500, 100000);
                new DoTask().execute(url);
            }
            public class DoTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                for (String urlVal : params) {
                   mPullParser = new PullParser(urlVal);
                    }
            mData = mPullParser.parse();
             ContentValues value = new ContentValues();
             value.put("weather", mData);
             mContentResolver.insert(mUri,value );
             return mData;
               }
             }
            private void setImage(){  //
                int smsCount = rnsmc.getCountNewSms();
                int callCount = rnsmc.getCountMissedCall();
                if( smsCount > 0 && callCount >0){
                    mIv.setImageResource(R.drawable.bump);
                    count = 1;
                }
             }
            private void setWeather(String weather){///

                }
```

Comment: are you using AsyncTask ?

Comment: @Hardy yes! Hmm .. setweather, it converts the image by parsing the weather.
parsing is on asyctask.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `asynctask` as following.

```
@Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

//Start your custom animation here OR display progress dialog
}

doInBackground(....)
{

 // code for getting data from webservice
}

onPostExecute(...)
{
// stop your animation OR dialog
}
```

See this [Example](http://karanbalkar.com/2012/10/tutorial-5-custom-progressdialog-with-asynctask/). Hope it helps.

Comment: I am a veryveryvery beginner of Android.
Do I need to use the asynctask must?

Comment: Yes you need to use asynctask.

Comment: See [This example](http://androiddevelopmentworld.blogspot.in/2013/04/how-to-display-image-from-url-in-android.html) where i am using asynctask for display image from url. Its easy to understand and implement. If you have any issue then just paste your code, i will give you idea how to implement asynctask.